# No overload matches this call in react-google-maps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, google-maps, react-google-maps

I am facing a issue in react with typescript,
I am using **react-google-maps** for google map but I am getting **eslint** error
here is the screen shot of error[image]

I tried all the things that i know but i am not able to find what is the issue.

Here is the code

```js
// Import React
import * as React from 'react'

// Import necessary components for React Google Maps
import {
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,
  InfoWindow,
  Marker
} from 'react-google-maps'

// Import custom styles to customize the style of Google Map
const styles = require('./GoogleMapStyles.json')

// Import custom icon for map marker
// const mapMarker = require('./GoogleMapMarker.svg')

interface Input {
    googleMapURL: string;
    containerElement: React.ReactElement<any, string | React.JSXElementConstructor<any>>;
    mapElement: React.ReactElement<any, string | React.JSXElementConstructor<any>>;
    isInfoboxVisible: boolean;
    infoboxMessage: string;
    handleInfoboxClick: () => void;
    handleMarkerClick: (message: string, lang:number, lat:number) => void;
    infoboxPosY: number;
    infoboxPosX: number;
}
// Google Map component
const GoogleMapComponentWithMarker = withScriptjs<Input>(
  withGoogleMap((props: Input) => (
    <GoogleMap
      defaultZoom={13}
      defaultCenter={{
        lat: 40.7484445,
        lng: -73.9878584
      }}
      defaultOptions={{
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        draggable: true,
        keyboardShortcuts: false,
        scaleControl: true,
        scrollwheel: true,
        styles: styles
      }}
    >
      <Marker
        icon={{
          url:
            'data:image/svg+xml;utf-8, \
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="45" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path fill="#e74c3c" d="M252.55 0h5.95c33.76.52 67.31 11.19 94.97 30.59 27.22 18.94 48.77 45.95 61.03 76.77 13.14 32.69 15.69 69.52 7.17 103.71-4.69 19.44-13.24 37.77-24.07 54.54-43.51 75.53-86.86 151.15-130.3 226.72-3.45 6.37-7.56 12.4-10.59 18.97l-.03.7h-1.21c-1.09-3.48-3.25-6.44-4.99-9.6-45.11-78.52-90.2-157.06-135.34-235.57-11.21-17.1-19.98-35.9-24.82-55.81-8.5-34.15-5.96-70.94 7.16-103.6 12.26-30.85 33.82-57.89 61.07-76.84C185.94 11.35 219.12.74 252.55 0m-6.26 64.44c-35.07 2.83-67.55 24.7-84.18 55.59-12.65 23.12-15.96 51.04-9.61 76.57 5.91 23.77 20.39 45.27 40.13 59.76 15.73 11.8 34.8 19.03 54.4 20.59 25.3 2.2 51.34-4.95 71.73-20.15 21.42-15.44 36.67-39.16 41.84-65.06 3.31-17.12 2.61-35.08-2.44-51.8-7.43-24.97-24.51-46.85-46.76-60.35-19.27-12.01-42.54-17.21-65.11-15.15z" /><path fill="#c0392b" d="M246.29 64.44c22.57-2.06 45.84 3.14 65.11 15.15 22.25 13.5 39.33 35.38 46.76 60.35 5.05 16.72 5.75 34.68 2.44 51.8-5.17 25.9-20.42 49.62-41.84 65.06-20.39 15.2-46.43 22.35-71.73 20.15-19.6-1.56-38.67-8.79-54.4-20.59-19.74-14.49-34.22-35.99-40.13-59.76-6.35-25.53-3.04-53.45 9.61-76.57 16.63-30.89 49.11-52.76 84.18-55.59m1.83 42.76c-15.04 1.8-29.3 9.21-39.45 20.45-10.03 10.95-16.02 25.5-16.56 40.34-.67 14.62 3.9 29.41 12.74 41.08 9.61 12.84 24.18 21.87 39.99 24.58 13.71 2.43 28.21.28 40.55-6.18 13.67-7.04 24.63-19.16 30.18-33.5 5.65-14.32 5.84-30.7.55-45.15-4.99-13.88-15-25.86-27.72-33.3-12.03-7.13-26.42-10.05-40.28-8.32z" /></svg>' // This may not work in <=IE11
        }}
        position={{
          lat: 40.7484445,
          lng: -73.9878584
        }}
        onClick={(e) => {
          props.handleMarkerClick(
            'Custom Google Map marker with infobox!',
            40.7484445,
            -73.9878584
          )
        }}
      />
      {props.isInfoboxVisible && (
        <InfoWindow
          position={{
            lat: props.infoboxPosY,
            lng: props.infoboxPosX
          }}
          onCloseClick={() => props.handleInfoboxClick()}
        >
          <div>
            <h4>{props.infoboxMessage}</h4>
          </div>
        </InfoWindow>
      )}
    </GoogleMap>
  ))
)

// Export Google Map component
export default GoogleMapComponentWithMarker
```

IF you check i have imported `GoogleMap` from `react-google-maps`

For simple javascript it is working but for typescript it is giving this error
please help

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
const GoogleMap = require('react-google-maps').GoogleMap;
```

instead of

```
import { GoogleMap } from 'react-google-maps';
```

Some packages have wrong type information, this way you can ignore it.